# Amcharts - Specific color for each line

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I use the following chart: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/reversed-value-axis/

Now I want to set the color for each line manually.
For example: "United Kingdom" - line with color #ff0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lineColor inside graphs array like:

```
{
    "balloonText": "place taken by UK in [[category]]: [[value]]",
    "bullet": "round",
    "title": "United Kingdom",
    "valueField": "uk",
    "fillAlphas": 0,

    "lineColor": "#ff0000"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgtc9djp/